# Better way to join multiple tables using SQL

Tags: sql

I am messing around with the toy databases on [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all) for learning SQL and I was trying to make a table that allowed me to find out the following information on a given OrderID:

- Name of the products in the order.
- Total cost of each product in the order (so if they ordered 10 of 1 item, what is the cost).
- Name of the suppliers of those products.
- Name of the shipper for the order.

I ended up achieving it through this code:

```
SELECT 
    Price * Quantity AS TotalCost, 
    ProductName, SupplierName, ShipperName 
FROM
    (SELECT * 
     FROM 
         (SELECT * 
          FROM 
              (SELECT * 
               FROM Products
               LEFT JOIN Suppliers ON Products.SupplierID = Suppliers.SupplierID) AS Products
          LEFT JOIN 
              OrderDetails ON Products.ProductID = OrderDetails.ProductID) AS OrderDetails
     LEFT JOIN 
         Orders ON OrderDetails.OrderID = Orders.OrderID) AS Orders
LEFT JOIN 
    Shippers ON Orders.ShipperID = Shippers.ShipperID 
WHERE 
    Orders.OrderDetails.OrderID = 10248;
```

However this seems like a total mess and I assume there must be a better way of achieving the same result. I did look around at other threads to see if I could find other ways, and the threads seemed to suggest that these subqueries are not necessary and that I could just chain the JOINs together without using subqueries, but when I tried this I got errors from the W3School compiler. Not sure if this is a problem with the website itself or if the error was on my end. For example, if I try this I get an error:

```
SELECT 
    Price * Quantity AS TotalCost, 
    ProductName, SupplierName, ShipperName
FROM
    Products
LEFT JOIN 
    Suppliers ON Products.SupplierID = Suppliers.SupplierID
LEFT JOIN 
    OrderDetails ON Products.ProductID = OrderDetails.ProductID
LEFT JOIN 
    Orders ON OrderDetails.OrderID = Orders.OrderID
LEFT JOIN 
    Shippers ON Orders.ShipperID = Shippers.ShipperID 
WHERE 
    Orders.OrderDetails.OrderID = 10248;
```

Error:

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Products.SupplierID=Suppliers.SupplierID LEFT JOIN OrderDetails ON Products.ProductID=OrderDetails.ProductID LEFT JOIN Orders ON OrderDetails.OrderID=Orders.OrderID LEFT JOIN Shippers ON Orders.ShipperID=Shippers.ShipperID'.

Comment: I highly recommend using *short* table aliases.

Comment: This is not a MySql error. Are you using MS Access?

Comment: My mistake, I am just using SQL on W3Schools to play around a bit, the error came from there.

Comment: Your query would be syntactically correct in any database I know of except MS Access for which you must parenthesize each join. I'm sure the site where you are studying SQL provides info about how to join properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably with this:

```
WHERE Orders.OrderDetails.OrderID = 10248;
```

Unless the database is called "Orders" (is it?), You appear to be referring to two tables at once. Use either:

```
WHERE Orders.OrderID = 10248;
```

or

```
WHERE OrderDetails.OrderID = 10248;
```

EDIT:

Assuming you mean [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_join_left), you need to add parentheses and make the correction I mention above. I suppose they are requiring parentheses in this test so that it works in Access as well as others.

```
SELECT Price*Quantity AS TotalCost, ProductName, SupplierName, ShipperName
FROM ((((Products 
LEFT JOIN Suppliers ON Products.SupplierID = Suppliers.SupplierID)
LEFT JOIN OrderDetails ON Products.ProductID = OrderDetails.ProductID)
LEFT JOIN Orders ON OrderDetails.OrderID = Orders.OrderID)
LEFT JOIN Shippers ON Orders.ShipperID = Shippers.ShipperID) 
WHERE OrderDetails.OrderID = 10248;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify from which table those columns come from. You can't just say SELECT Price when you have multiple tables joined. For example, `Price*Quantity` would need to be something like `Products.Price*Orders.Quantity`

Comment: Ok, the first query works for me regardless of whether I specify the table or not. The second query did not get fixed by adding the specific tables where the columns originate from.

Answer (score 1):

You're not to far off. Please try the following version tidied up with tables aliases:

```
SELECT Price*Quantity AS TotalCost, ProductName, SupplierName, ShipperName
FROM Products p
LEFT JOIN Suppliers s ON p.SupplierID = s.SupplierID
LEFT JOIN OrderDetails od ON p.ProductID = od.ProductID
LEFT JOIN Orders o ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID
LEFT JOIN Shippers sh ON o.ShipperID = sh.ShipperID 
WHERE o.OrderID = 10248;
```

The only thing that is really changed is the WHERE clause.